# jQuery hide function wont work,

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi Im looking for a pop up window to appear on my homepage and for me to be able to turn it off using an X button.. 
Here is my CSS

```
.sign-up-modal {
width: 590px;
height: 464px;
position:fixed;
z-index:700;
top:180px;
left:50%;
background-image: url('images/youtubeconsole.png');
margin-left:-295px;
display:block;
}

.modalbackground {
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-image: url('images/modalbackground.png');
background-repeat: repeat;
position:fixed;
z-index:99999;
}

.youtubexbutton {
bottom: 12px;
right:13px;
position:absolute;
width:26px;
height:26px;
background-image:url('images/youtubex.png');
}

.youtubexbutton:hover {
background-image:url('images/youtubex-hover.png');
cursor:pointer;
}
```

In wordpress, in my header.php I have ...

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.youtubexbutton').click(function(){
    jQuery('.sign-up-modal').hide();
    });

    jQuery('.youtubexbutton').click(function(){
    jQuery('.modalbackground').hide();
});

}


</script>
```

In my homepage I have...

```
<div class="sign-up-modal">
<div class="youtubexbutton"></div>
</div>
```

Although the modal appears, when I press `youtubexbutton` nothing happens, I was hoping both `.modalbackground` and `.sign-up-modal` with leave the page.

Comment: You are missing `)` for document ready handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax error. There's a `)` missing:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('.youtubexbutton').click(function(){
    jQuery('.sign-up-modal').hide();
    });

    jQuery('.youtubexbutton').click(function(){
    jQuery('.modalbackground').hide();
});

})
```

Comment: BTW: you should use the Google Chrome's Javascript console or Firebug if you use Firefox, those are very useful tools (I'd say essential) to develop Javascript

Comment: thanks I need to practice using that alright